# Is this php/mysql expression (which sets the timezone of connection) safe enough?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, timezone

Is this expression is safe or does this approach has vulnerabilities?

```
$pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=test', 'user', 'password');
$pdo->exec('SET time_zone = "' . date_default_timezone_get() . '"');
```

Comment: Looks fine to me - the attack this, you'd need to override that function which is a PHP default.

Comment: for maximum safety, you should be escaping that value. it's conceivable that someone could hack the system timezone definitions file and insert a brand new [BobbyTables](http://bobby-tables.com) zone just to subvert your system. **ANY** external data you're inserting into a query should be escaped at bare minimum. NEVER assume it's "safe".

Answer (score 0):

I would check first if `date_default_timezone_get()` returns a valid value, to avoid a query like: `SET time_zone = ""`.